# Can't Seem to Install Flutter- MacOs Big Sur 11.5.2

Tags: macos, flutter, installation, macos-big-sur

on running in a zsh terminal `vim ~/.zshrc`
pressing `I`  and entering

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/F/bin"
```

pressing
ESC KEY
and typing `:wq!`
and opening a new terminal window flutter --version says flutter command not found
attaching two screenshots the first one shows the location of F inside which flutter resides [image: Finder Location For F(which has flutter inside)]
and another which shows my exact output saved in  `vim ~/.zshrc`
what Am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: No pictures of code please.

Comment: export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/F/Flutter/bin"
missed the /flutter in the zshrc file which was causing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use vs code to edit path ,
Install vs code and then

Try these steps :

1. code $HOME/.zshrc
2. export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/<path to flutter/bin>

Comment: Hi Addy, I've installed VSC code on my system, where to write all of this inside vsc? thanks!

Comment: just write any dir. of terminal.

Comment: I'm sorry an absolute newbie here,  how do i do that?  i have the vsc application open should i create a new file?

Comment: relax bro !  just open terminal app , and then type "code $HOME/.zshrc" hit enter , .... it will open .zshrc file and then add "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/<path to flutter/bin>" and save .zshrc using ctrl+s

Comment: Edited in vsc code, Flutter seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the path to .zshrc file, have you reloaded the .zshrc?
Try source ~/.zshrc.

Comment: Yes, I've reloaded the .zhsrc file, where do i have to execute this source ~/.zshrc command?

Comment: In the terminal, doesn't matter the location, this is the exact location of your zshrc file - ~/ this is the equivalent of $HOME which is the /User/{yourusernamme} folder, also known as home folder.